# v-once rendered twice on a template

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vue-component

I use this to show message on a page that provide info about that item, but when i clicked the button that showed on the table (the button are showed on each row), all the button in each row are clicked so it makes the `b-modal` showed many times of each button in a row. i have added `v-once` but still the `b-modal` are render twice or as many as the button available on the table.

here my HTML,

```
  <template slot="action" slot-scope="data">
     <b-btn v-b-modal.modal2 variant="primary">View</b-btn>

      <b-modal v-once id="modal2" size="lg" title="View Surat">
        <p class="my-2">View Surat</p>
      </b-modal>
  </template>
```

Here my full `.vue`  [code](https://gist.github.com/mandaputra8/673f18ef06be4f27f701caf9a5031e42)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v-once` works differently from how you expect it to behave. **It does not only append some element once to the dom!** What `v-once` does instead is render the template of a sepcific component only once, the [vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once) says:

> On subsequent re-renders, the element/component and all its children
> will be treated as static content and skipped. This can be used to
> optimize update performance.

However this is not a re-render of the same element and it doesn't stop the implemenation of your `b-modal` to be appended to the dom mulitple times.

A possible workaround I would suggest is using a variable in your parent's component data to determine wether the modal has been opened and trigger it with a method on the button, like so:

```
  <template slot="action" slot-scope="data">
     <b-btn @click="openModal" variant="primary">View</b-btn>

      <b-modal :active.sync="isOpen" size="lg" title="View Surat">
        <p class="my-2">View Surat</p>
      </b-modal>
  </template>
```

And in your component:

```
data() {
   return {
     // your other data
     isOpen: false
   }
},
methods: {
  openModal () {
    this.isOpen = true
   }
}
```

To be fair I haven't tested this in a life project but from what the [buefy documentation](https://buefy.github.io/#/documentation/modal) says, this should give you the expected behaviour.

Comment: sorry for long time no reply, i forgot the index of the array. it work now like this ```v-b-modal.modal('$index')```